# Find the number of re-occuring words in two strings in python

Tags: python, string, nltk

I would like to know if there is a library or a function that can return a number if the input is two strings and the output should be the number of re-occurring words in the two strings an example...

input:

```
string 1= my name is user
string 2= my friend is here
```

output:

```
2
```

as "my" and "is" is repeated in both the strings...i heard that nltk can help me with that, if true can someone please guide me to the function...please help me out

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about `nltk` - seems slightly overkill (unless you want some advanced tokenization). If you can tokenize words just by spaces, then you can use sets as follows:

```
>>> a = 'one two three four five'
>>> b = 'three blind mice'
>>> set(a.split()).intersection(b.split())
set(['three'])
```

And take the length of that...

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary :( Those captchas do appear at the most inconvenient times! (and some of them I have no idea what they're supposed to be!)

Comment: Mostly they appear whenever IP address changes, and sometimes they appear for no reason.

Answer (score -1):

```
res=set(a.split())&set(b.split())
print len(res)
```

Comment: How's that different from @Jon's answer?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: sorry, I meant to say equivalent method for the above solution..